# How to increase storage in Lumia 520?

Tags: 8.1, lumia, lumia-520, storage

So in my Lumia I have the internal storage and I added a mini SD memory.
However I just can save Media content on the SD card but the apps are still installed on internal storage and I struggle with space. Is there is any solution for this?

I cant even upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile from Windows 8 because of it.

Comment: Did you try to install the Upgrade Advisor app in order to upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile? It will do some cleaning out of unused internal phone cache and thereby give you some more space before the upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

You can move majority of apps to SD card via Storage sense. However apps like whatsapp, Xbox music cannot be moved to SD card.

In order to move apps to SD card:

1. Open Storage sense
2. Go to Phone->Apps and Games
3. Select an app
4. Click move to SD card button.
5. Repeat these steps for all the apps you want to move.

> I cant even upgrade to windows 10 from windows 8 because of it.

Lumia 520 and other 512MB RAM devices is not eligible for Windows 10 upgrade.

Comment: If you mean "phone storage" >"apps+games"

 then I have message manage or install apps from the App. list. Or I am in the wrong place?

Comment: Just want to respond to the other guy who responded and want to say that windows 10 does work on the 520. I am using it right now. Granted it is slower than 8.1 but it has more features.. up to you whether or not you want to upgrade. And yeah all you can really do is delete things, move them to your SD card or get a bigger SD card. Also trying deleting your temp files in the storage sense app.

Comment: @WilliamHughes I didn't say Windows 10 will not work on L520. I only said it is not eligible for Windows 10 upgrade. What you are using is an insider preview. Installing an insider preview is not an upgrade. Insider preview is a beta version of the OS while an upgrade will be a stable version of the OS. Microsoft has clarified that there will be no upgrade to Lumia 520.

Comment: @JohnGoldman you are in the right place. You should see the list of installed apps(which are in your phone memory) there. Click on an app and click on the move button.